# How to append data to CSV

Tags: c#

After I create a excel file, how should I add more data that each time the method is called should append to the bottom of the log file under datetime, name, message? Any hint?

```
public bool UpdateLogile(string ModuleName, string ProcessName, string Message) {
        try {
            string strPath = Properties.Settings.Default.SystemLogPath;
            string strFileName = Properties.Settings.Default.SystemLogFileName;
            string strPathAndFile = string.Concat(strPath, "\\", strFileName);

            if (!File.Exists (strPathAndFile )) { // the file doesn't exist, create it 
            using(FileStream fs = new FileStream (strPathAndFile , FileMode.Create)) {
                    //nothing else to do; object will colse on its own
                }
            using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter (strPathAndFile , true)) {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.Append(string.Concat("Date.Time", "\t", "ModuleName", "\t", "Message"));
                    sw.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
                }
            }

            //append to file with the current date-time, ModuleName, Message
            // 12/12/2018 11:33:55 004 pm
            return true;

        }
        catch (Exception ex) { return false; }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you're writing to CSV file. Is that correct?

Comment: If the server/computer on which your application is running, then you can use Microsoft Object Library. It's simple, just check this link : http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-create-excel.htm

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it appears you are writing to a text file in CSV format, and not an actual Excel file (which is quite a bit more complex).

So, as with any other text file, it appears the issue is with how you are opening the file.

```
new FileStream(strPathAndFile , FileMode.Create);
```

If you look at documentation for the [FileMode Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode(v=vs.110).aspx), you'll see that `FileMode.Create` specifies that:

> If the file already exists, it will be overwritten.

I would think it would be as simple as using `FileMode.Append` instead. This value will cause new content to be appended to any existing file. (The file will still be created if it does not already exist.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are actually after creating Microsoft Excel files, and not files that could be imported to Excel, you should definatly include OpenXML into your project.

It is rater simple to create real Excel files.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx